# Convert the value of a dictionary in a column into a particular number in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
Date                      Aspect   
21-01-2020                {word1:'positive', word2:'negative', word3:'neutral'}
22-01-2020                {word1:'negative', word2:'negative', word3:'neutral', word4:'neutral'}
23-01-2020                {word1:'positive', word2:'positive', word3:'negative'}
```

I would like to replace positive to 1, negative to -1 and neutral to 0.

Expected Output:

```
Date                      Aspect   
21-01-2020                {word1:1, word2:-1, word3:0}
22-01-2020                {word1:-1, word2:-1, word3:0, word4:0}
23-01-2020                {word1:1, word2:1, word3:-1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If column `Aspect` is filled by dictionaries use dict comprehension with mapping by helper dict:

```
d = {'positive':1, 'negative':-1, 'neutral':0}
df['Aspect'] = df['Aspect'].apply(lambda x: {k: d[v] for k, v in x.items()})
#alternative
#df['Aspect'] = [{k: d[v] for k, v in x.items()} for x in df['Aspect']]

print (df)
         Date                                             Aspect
0  21-01-2020             {'word1': 1, ' word2': -1, 'word3': 0}
1  22-01-2020  {'word1': -1, 'word2': -1, 'word3': 0, 'word4'...
2  23-01-2020              {'word1': 1, 'word2': 1, 'word3': -1}
```